# Ajax upload in Ctools Modal Window

Tags: chaos-tool-suite, javascript

I have node creation form in a popup dialog box. I decided to give it a try using ctools modal window. But I seem to be getting errors when I upload an image into a image field after using browse to select it.

```
Warning: call_user_func_array() [function.call-user-func-array]: First argument is expected to be a valid callback, 'node_form' was given in drupal_retrieve_form() (line 795 of /var/www/html/test/includes/form.inc).
Notice: Undefined index: #node in comment_form_node_form_alter() (line 1193 of /var/www/html/test/modules/comment/comment.module).
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in comment_form_node_form_alter() (line 1210 of /var/www/html/test/modules/comment/comment.module).
Notice: Undefined index: #node in menu_form_node_form_alter() (line 629 of /var/www/html/test/modules/menu/menu.module).
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in menu_form_node_form_alter() (line 629 of /var/www/html/test/modules/menu/menu.module).
Notice: Undefined index: #node in menu_form_node_form_alter() (line 630 of /var/www/html/test/modules/menu/menu.module).
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in menu_form_node_form_alter() (line 630 of /var/www/html/test/modules/menu/menu.module).
Notice: Undefined index: field_artwork_image in file_ajax_upload() (line 271 of /var/www/html/test/modules/file/file.module).
Notice: Undefined index: #suffix in file_ajax_upload() (line 280 of /var/www/html/test/modules/file/file.module)
```

Below is my code

```
function portfolio_cust_node_add_modal_callback($js = FALSE) {
  global $user;

  //If people are not using JS. I just tell them "sorry" it is '2012'
  if (!$js) return "Javascript required";
  ctools_include('node.pages', 'node', '');
  ctools_include('modal');
  ctools_include('ajax');

 // Create a blank node object here.
  $node = (object) array(
    'uid' => $user->uid,
    'name' => (isset($user->name) ? $user->name : ''),
    'type' => 'psuedo_portfolio',
    'language' => LANGUAGE_NONE,
    );

  $form_state = array(
    'title' => t('Add Portfolio'),
    'ajax' => TRUE,
  );
  $form_state['build_info']['args'] = array($node);
  drupal_add_library('system', 'ui.dialog');
  // change this to your type node form
  $output = ctools_modal_form_wrapper('psuedo_portfolio_node_form', $form_state);

  // This means the form has been exectued
  if (!empty($form_state['executed'])) {
    $output = array();
    // Close the modal
    $output[] = ctools_modal_command_dismiss();
  }

  print ajax_render($output);
  exit;

}
```

I am planning to use colorbox module or some other method which uses a iframe instead of how ctools implements the modal dialog.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I faced the same problem, and I managed to solve it using [merlinofchaos's suggestion](http://drupal.org/node/1600934#comment-6041846). I used `form_load_include()` just after form_state initialization:

```
  $form_state = array(
    'title' => t('Add new deal'),
    'ajax' => TRUE,
    'node' => $node,
  );

  $form_state['build_info']['args'] = isset($form_state['build_info']['args']) ? $form_state['build_info']['args'] : array($node);
  form_load_include($form_state, 'inc', 'node', 'node.pages');
```

Comment: I used overlay paths which uses iframe. However this is also working thanks!! will use it the next time.

Answer (score 0):

this fixed for me:

http://drupal.org/node/1336212#comment-6049694

Add the following lines to a [`hook_menu_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_menu_alter/7) implementation:

```
$items['file/ajax']['file'] = 'node.pages.inc';
$items['file/ajax']['file path'] = drupal_get_path('module', 'node');
```