# Modal form file upload is not working

Tags: 7, chaos-tool-suite, modal-dialogs

I am trying to use ctools modal form to edit node form. This form is containing a file field. The Form is rendering properly. When I try to upload a file on clicking upload button, file field has been deleted from the page. I tried to debug via firebug to see the response, it was correct as we get without modal form.

I added the following code in modal callback.

```
ctools_include('node.pages', 'node', '');
ctools_include('modal');
ctools_include('ajax');

$form_state['build_info']['args'] = isset($form_state['build_info']['args']) ? $form_state['build_info']['args'] : array($node);
form_load_include($form_state, 'inc', 'node', 'node.pages');
```

I took the reference from [Ajax upload in Ctools Modal Window](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/38634/ajax-upload-in-ctools-modal-window) but it still having problem.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're implementing the right Drupal API syntax which requires `$form_state` to be the reference to the original array, so it can be properly modified through certain hooks.

For example if you're using `form_load_include()` in [hook_form_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7), make sure you're following the right API syntax which is:

```
hook_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id)
```

(note the `&`) otherwise [`form_load_include()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21form.inc/function/form_load_include/7) can't perform alterations of your current state of the form (`$form_state`).